# What is the right way to embed a Flash movie for XHTML compliance?

Tags: flash, xhtml, adobe, actionscript-2, embed

I have a simple movie that has a tiny bit of Actionscript 2.0.

1. What is the best way to embed a flash movie for XHTML compliance?
2. Which version should I export for?

The code that Flash automatically outputs is so bloated, I'm not sure what I need. Also, I noticed that a Macromedia URL is in the code, and now that Adobe owns Flash, I wonder if this is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to embed a flash file in HTML is using swfobject by Google : http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

In the end it goes like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = {
  name1: "hello",
  name2: "world",
  name3: "foobar"
};
var params = {
  menu: "false"
};
var attributes = {
  id: "myDynamicContent",
  name: "myDynamicContent"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I really like that swfobject idea